# Understanding indexes and performance as they relate to indexed column and non-indexed column data in the same row

Tags: postgresql

I have some tables that are around 100 columns wide. I haven't normalized them because to put it back together would require almost 3 dozen joins and am not sure it would perform any better... haven't tested it yet (I will) so can't say for sure.

Anyway, that really isn't the question. I have been indexing columns in these tables that I know will be pulled frequently, so something like 50 indexes per table.

I got to thinking though. These columns will never be pulled by themselves and are meaningless without the primary key (basically an item number). The PK will always be used for the join and even in simple `SELECT` queries, it will have to be a specified column so the data makes sense.

That got me thinking further about indexes and how they work. As I understand them the locations of a values are committed to memory for that column so it is quickly found in a query.

For example, if you have:

```
SELECT itemnumber, expdate
FROM items;
```

And both `itemnumber` and `expdate` are indexed, is that excessive and really adding any benefit? Is it sufficient to just index `itemnumber` and the index will know that `expdate`, or anything else that is queried for that item, is on the same row?

Secondly, if multiple columns constitute a primary key, should the index include them grouped together, or is individually sufficient?

For example,

```
CREATE INDEX test_index ON table (pk_col1, pk_col2, pk_col3);
```

vs.

```
CREATE INDEX test_index1 ON table (pk_col1);
CREATE INDEX test_index2 ON table (pk_col2);
CREATE INDEX test_index3 ON table (pk_col3);
```

Thanks for clearing that up in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh oh, there is a mountain of basics that you still have to learn.

I'd recommend that you read the PostgreSQL documentation and the excellent book [“SQL Performance Explained”](http://use-the-index-luke.com/).

I'll give you a few pointers to get you started:

- Whenever you create a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint, PostgreSQL automatically creates a unique index over all the columns of that constraint. So you don't have to create that index explicitly (but if it is a multicolumn index, it sometimes is useful to create another index on any but the first column).
- Indexes are relevant to conditions in the `WHERE` clause and the `GROUP BY` clause and to some extent for table joins. They are irrelevant for entries in the `SELECT` list. An index provides an efficient way to get the part of a table that satisfies a certain condition; an (unsorted) access to *all* rows of a table will never benefit from an index.

Don't sprinkle your schema with indexes randomly, since indexes use space and make all data modification slow.

Use them where you *know* that they will do good: on columns on which a foreign key is defined, on columns that appear in `WHERE` clauses and contain many different values, on columns where your examination of the execution plan (with `EXPLAIN`) suggests that you can expect a performance benefit.

Comment: Yea my explanation was pretty poor as I was in a hurry. What I am getting at is if I have `SELECT itemnumber, expdate FROM items WHERE itemnumber = 'ABC123' AND expdate = current_date` is it really necessary to index `expdate` since the index on `itemnumber` already identifies the row? In this case `itemnumber` is the PK and `expdate` just describes the item but is a helpful data point. I'll start reading through that book.

Comment: Also, came across this comment researching what you said about PostgreSQL automatically creating indexes on PKs. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31517. Basically, how I setup the tables months ago and erred on the side of indexing anything that would potentially be in a `JOIN` or `WHERE`. But still just curious if that is necessary given an item is the PK and anything else in the `WHERE` should just be an "offset" of x-columns from the PK... if that makes sense.

Comment: Addressing your first comment: If one of the conditions in the query specifies the primary key, PostgreSQL will only use the primary key index to locate the row. Other indexes are useless for the query. To your second comment: It is bad practice to create an index on everything unless it is a data warehouse where nothing ever gets modified.